# How can I make TypeScript infer the correct types for these parameters?

Tags: typescript

I’m trying to make a library generic across promise libraries, but I’ve come across a case where, within the same type, a single type parameter is inferred to be two different types:

```js
interface PromiseClass<A, P extends PromiseLike<A>> {
    new(
        callback: (resolve: (value?: A | P) => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void) => void): P;
}

interface Options<A, P extends PromiseLike<A>> {
    promise?: PromiseClass<A, P>;
}

declare class PromisePool<
    A,                        // the type of value returned by the source
    P extends PromiseLike<A>, // the type of Promise returned by the source
    P2 extends PromiseLike<A>, // the type of Promise specified in `options`
    > {
    constructor(
        source: P,
        concurrency: number,
        options?: Options<A, P2>
    );

    start(): P2;
}

class FakePromise<T> implements PromiseLike<T> {
    constructor(
        _callback: (
            resolve: (value?: T | FakePromise<T>) => void,
            reject: (reason?: any) => void) => void) {
    }

    then<TResult1 = T, TResult2 = never>(
        _onfulfilled?: ((value: T) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | undefined | null,
        _onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<TResult2>) | undefined | null):
        PromiseLike<TResult1 | TResult2> {
        throw new Error("stub");
    }
};


// erroneously inferred as PromisePool<unknown, FakePromise<number>,
// PromiseLike<unknown>> instead of PromisePool<number, FakePromise<number>,
// PromiseLike<number>> i.e. A is inferred as both `unknown` and `number`
const pool = new PromisePool(
    new FakePromise<number>((_resolve, _reject) => true), 1);

// error:
// Type 'PromiseLike<unknown>' is not assignable to type 'PromiseLike<number>'.
//   Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'number'.
const promise: PromiseLike<number> = pool.start();
```

([Playground link.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYFtgGcIDCANnLrgDwCCANGshAB6QgAmuamO%20AMsANYQqAPiHIA3gChk05CAgB3ABRSZqhHCJEARoj4AuZIqgRcGIgDcIBxeY0BXCAH4DlZAB80ASmQBeUeYxgFlpjACsIBDBrY1IMEGdkOBAAT28-ZACgtP9Alk8DVABuCQBfCQlQSFhEFAB5AAcwYDiKGjpGZjYObDwIXgFhUUlVes5ehPQe-GJSVtpUIWKyiRYIkmNkBBIybq4IVAwzchVpNtVzi8vkAHpr5DAACxQwZPqUDBgM%20xRjMDsoOQsZBaZL3J7IUz-JAndpMCCsdiTPb9QSUIS0W5g56vd6fJG9ZC-f6A4Ggx4oSFQaGqVAAJnocIRu16KOEGLu5PuOOQH2Z%20AhbwQwBgwAgQNAyAABhhGs0QLhJTChjCEC0wFA7JEMFBlFdKUgCtQYWo4gh-sYQAhkgYQHYsFpoEarjKmi0Eg1XfKqPNaUIYZ5ijDcGA4FAwIp8mhaUtyltZsgAGJwAT4-DkAAqomAWHqRAgWHhYERYx4-EEmfEKrVGq1OuNMgA%20upNDoEPpDPWLsZTBYrIZbEQHAl0%205E8n9iXy0Jshlck6rjIwhEooYYqZ4gYkqlfDksjvZ3vhjJlqpySAMwAlEx2IhgACMvmQ6do6avuBvYHpPlkEEsUCEuqXA2cQwDeIqaGKCSKDY3wGOmM6vtet4Ph4qZ9GWl5Ife06jnYrAQCKJIeLamjzhcwEgEukSQdYRgQLEICbikCFvh%209KoZOrKIe%20t6%20t4Hh4ashFiqOJFEPknZ8uhAzcR%20KFPqxvHKlcjyYPIP7qQAolAmA6gARMGdhaHpAYwmUJSBhImLQJgcgYHYuBEKCoAwDZImkFJBxHHhfAgBg8ggLQSYppO5C2va0DolZdxoayPl%20QFIjIKAwb0UCvJoV5RBhXaDpQEF45oTlEX-kamKxRh4V5UlwAAHQQLVyCuHgyUgK5OnuewWgYI8Urxf5ICSokrBSlV0CKqq8pgMg9SHEQj5yOpmVzYB0iLWOIVTIIY3-tBDbdmYli0PtEDhJEM7qg4ni0HepnRfQOnano93ptyADkFUDP1iVvcl7B%20dNszAAA5iAcBaHm9wYFybzIB9nGVblkVvbV93SK9sNvd9IC-S1AOJGQINgxDzzQy8mM7SjEiTcGM2TgUCMDDtojfrNZi1cGobhqZQA))

It works if I specify the full type of `pool`:

```js
const pool: PromisePool<number, FakePromise<number>, PromiseLike<number>> = new PromisePool(
    new FakePromise<number>((_resolve, _reject) => true), 1);
```

How can I tell TypeScript that `pool.start` will return a `PromiseLike<number>` without having to write it out?

Comment: Do you want to infer number from this: new FakePromise<number>((_resolve, _reject) => true), 1); ?

Comment: Yes, more or less.

Answer (score 1):

Just get rid of second and third generic arguments (P, P2) from this class:

```js
declare class PromisePool<
    A,
    > {
    constructor(
        source: PromiseLike<A>,
        concurrency: number,
        options?: Options<A,  PromiseLike<A>>
    );

    start(): PromiseLike<A>;
}
```

Full example:

```js
interface PromiseClass<A, P extends PromiseLike<A>> {
    new(
        callback: (resolve: (value?: A | P) => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void) => void): P;
}

interface Options<A, P extends PromiseLike<A>> {
    promise?: PromiseClass<A, P>;
}

declare class PromisePool<
    A,
    > {
    constructor(
        source: PromiseLike<A>,
        concurrency: number,
        options?: Options<A,  PromiseLike<A>>
    );

    start(): PromiseLike<A>;
}

class FakePromise<T> implements PromiseLike<T> {
    constructor(
        _callback: (
            resolve: (value?: T | FakePromise<T>) => void,
            reject: (reason?: any) => void) => void) {
    }

    then<TResult1 = T, TResult2 = never>(
        _onfulfilled?: ((value: T) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | undefined | null,
        _onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<TResult2>) | undefined | null):
        PromiseLike<TResult1 | TResult2> {
        throw new Error("stub");
    }
};


// erroneously inferred as PromisePool<unknown, FakePromise<number>,
// PromiseLike<unknown>> instead of PromisePool<number, FakePromise<number>,
// PromiseLike<number>> i.e. A is inferred as both `unknown` and `number`
const pool = new PromisePool(
    new FakePromise<number>((_resolve, _reject) => true), 1);


const promise = pool.start(); // ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYFtgGcIDCANnLrgDwCCANGshAB6QgAmuamO%20AMsANYQqAPiHIA3gFgAUMlnIQEAO4AKaXPXIEcIkQBGiPgC5kyqBFwYiANwjHlV7QFcIAfmOVkAHzQBKZAF5RKwxgFlozACsIBDA7M1IMEDdkOBAATz9A5GDQzKCQlh9jVABuaQBfaWlQSFhEFAB5AAcwYESKGjpGZjYObDwIXgFhUUkZOSbOAeT0fvxiUg7aVCEyqUqpaRZokjNNEjI%20rghUDEtyNTkaS9lRm812sChHGIwoVXGNZAtHKCRiqY8fiCShCaj3dQIRIIX5mEAINLGECOLC6aDgz4aDAtNogXDJZqtdpUWhHAZDEEie4%20Nb3XBgOBQMDKIpkoHDUFrDbSBAHdgAMTgAlmx3IABVRMAsE0iBAsBBwOwReTgeK7pioXini8wG8Pl9ZAB9LQ6fQIIwmCEGswWay2EwOIjOZJirzIQXCwGCCV5bIFDEGjSRaKxEzxCxJYypDIBfK5WN%20%20NjdTczFgAAWCvFACVzI4iGAAIwBZBi2hi3O4fNgABMJYUNigQn1BsNiRg%20ZgwB0EBYyWU9ic9rFvoreYLxe8yvZ3sr1cLQj83kcrAgXYULDdyJ0AdbiWDMV7-dMEASICj6VHc4LdanXopOfHtcXbpX23Xva3%20aIRStsmngyqmOVYTm6wHVjW6qBhmmCKPISjIAAolAmDvAARPSji6GhNL3Bs5S0psUgAPTEfQKGJBAGCOLgRBpMgoAwNAZibqQbInGcRDkCufAgBgiggLQHonF65DIqi0BgtIpHsQ%20PF8QJIgMVqp6bhgMDsac5ziWiUBCUKIlzIIOmSRiMkAQ%20JlNpKAB0EA2cgHh4MpTEoZ%20bG6BgGbIAABvJ-EgD5KSsL5Vk%20TyjzIE0nH1ghAFaUQLayAocHCQBYkorpzbKIaNqWDYtC5RAUQxL62oQD4tCFrhRERVqUVegCRmWZlkkltFlg2fSjLMjSyAyRgfBAA)

**UPDATE**
What about this solution:

```js
interface PromiseClass<A, P extends PromiseLike<A>> {
    new(
        callback: (resolve: (value?: A | P) => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void) => void): P;
}

interface Options<A, P extends PromiseLike<A>> {
    promise?: PromiseClass<A, P>;
}

declare class PromisePool<
    A,
    T,
    > {
    constructor(
        source: PromiseLike<A>,
        concurrency: T,
        options?: Options<A,  PromiseLike<A>>
    );

    start(): PromiseLike<T>;
}

class FakePromise<T> implements PromiseLike<T> {
    constructor(
        _callback: (
            resolve: (value?: T | FakePromise<T>) => void,
            reject: (reason?: any) => void) => void) {
    }

    then<TResult1 = T, TResult2 = never>(
        _onfulfilled?: ((value: T) => TResult1 | PromiseLike<TResult1>) | undefined | null,
        _onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<TResult2>) | undefined | null):
        PromiseLike<TResult1 | TResult2> {
        throw new Error("stub");
    }
};


// erroneously inferred as PromisePool<unknown, FakePromise<number>,
// PromiseLike<unknown>> instead of PromisePool<number, FakePromise<number>,
// PromiseLike<number>> i.e. A is inferred as both `unknown` and `number`
const fake = new FakePromise<number>((_resolve, _reject) => true);
const pool = new PromisePool(fake, 1);
```

Comment: This doesn’t accomplish the same thing (taking in a promise of any kind and spitting out a promise of the type specified in the options), though, since the types are just flattened to `PromiseLike`.

Comment: This still flattens the types, unfortunately. The idea behind this is to establish in the types themselves that if you pass, say, Bluebird as the promise library in the options, then it returns Bluebird promises, whereas this solution would lose that information. Your answer has been useful, however, because it’s shown me that I don’t need to worry about the type of the promise passed to `start`, so thank you for that. I might be able to tweak this.